# How to create a customized URL in Firefox (as in Chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, search, browser-addons, url

Google Chrome has a very handy feature that I used to rely on a lot which basically lets you modify URL and map it into a string (keyword, character, letter etc) and also be able to pass arguments to it to search or direct you to the customized URL you want.

What I mean is, in my own implementation, I used to map the string `oed` to the customized URL `http://etymonline.com/?term=$1` in Chrome and searched for etymologies of words by typing, for instance `oed Prodigy` in the address bar which resulted in and lead me directly to the page in `http://etymonline.com/?term=Prodigy` URL of the website containing *only* the word's etymology entry.

I know about built-in `Add a Keyword` for this Search feature of Firefox, but that doesn't let you modify the string of the URL, meaning it results in `http://etymonline.com?allowed_in_frame=0&search=`, on the ground of the example above, which is not what I want because it searches and shows up multiple words in the result.

Moreover, add-ons such as [Add to Seach Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-to-search-bar/) and [Keyword Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keyword-search/) do not help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bookmarks manager, find the bookmark referencing `etymonline.com` and change the `Location` field to the desired URL. Exit the window (which will delete the value of the `Keyword` field), and then find the bookmark in the manager again and re-add the keyword.

Comment: Thanks! It indeed does the job, though it's somewhat strange how Firefox regards it as a bookmark.